# Is it possible to display two templates in single view from different modules?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I work on angularjs projects.
The project divided into modules, each module has it's own controller and templates.

I need to display two templates in single view from different modules, is it possible to implement?

Comment: You can use ng-include to reference other templates inside your view. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: @Martin, even if the template defined in another state?

Comment: Yes. If you provide some code for what you are trying to achieve, you can point to what is not working as you expect it and we can help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is..
you can create Directive for two templates in that html.

steps to implement:
1. in route file:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: "client/home/home.html",
                controller: "IndexCtrl",
                access: {
                    isloggedIn: false
                }
            })  
}]);
```

2. put this directives in home.html you want to load two different templates.
   "header-page" and "bottom"
3. create directive for the header-page and bottom.

   ```
   app.directive('headerPage', function () {
   return {
       restrict: "A",
       templateUrl: 'client/common/headerPage.html'
   };});

   app.directive('bottom', function () {
   return {
       restrict: "A",
       templateUrl: 'client/bottom/bottom.html'
   };});
   ```

Using this You are able to find two different Modules file on a single page.

Comment: but my templates defined in diffrent states

Comment: we can do it where ever it is.. you can check path of my home.html and also html of the directive's those are different..
if still you confuse then can you please share your working copy so I can see what you have did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is quite possible to implement this.

Please have a look at the below tutorial.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Hope it helps you!

Cheers